# How to copy a specific part from a cpp file (python)?

Tags: python

I want to copy a specific part from a cpp file in a temporary file, because I want to put that part in another cpp file, again in a specific position, but I don`t know exactly how I can do that. I tried something like this:

```
def search( var ):
    with open('...', 'r') as file1:
      for i, line in enumerate(file1):
         if var in line:
               return i       


x='setRunnable'
print search( x )
var = search( x )
print var
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(delete=False)


with open('...', 'r') as file1:
 for var, line in file1:
      if (line != '}'):
               temp.write(line1)

temp.seek(0)               
temp.read()
```

But I recive: "to many values to unpack"..
Can anyone help, please?

Update:
Input:
File1:

```
void doMemStage01()
{
  g_runFlow(g_flowm);                                                
  g_runFlow2(g_flowm2)                                 
}
void setRunStage01()
{
        g_runBli(60);
        g_runCoffe(100);
}
```

File2:

```
void doMemStage02()
{
  f_runFlow(g_flowm);                                                
  f_runFlow2(g_flowm2);                                 
}
void setRunStage02()
{
        f_runBli(60);
        f_runCoffe(100);
}
```

Output should be in file1, like this:
File 1:

```
void doMemStage01()
{
  g_runFlow(g_flowm);                                                
  g_runFlow2(g_flowm2);
  f_runFlow(g_flowm);                                                
  f_runFlow2(g_flowm2);                                    
}
void setRunStage01()
{
        g_runBli(60);
        g_runCoffe(100);
        f_runBli(60);
        f_runCoffe(100);
}
```

Comment: file1 represents a single line. you cant separate var and line .or whatever you trying to do

Comment: what is your input and expected output?

Comment: I updated the Input and expected Output.

Answer (score 1):

The "to many values to unpack" error raised in `for var, line in file1:` line because file walking returns only one value, not multiple values in every step. change this line to below form:

```
for var, line in enumerate(file1):
```

Also i suggest you for using `re` library, don't use `search` function and replace your code by below code:

```
func_code = ""
x="setRunnable"

with open('...', 'r') as file1:
    func_code = re.search('void\s+%s\w*\(\)[^{]*.*([^}]+)' % x, file1.read(), re.M)

if func_code:
    with open('temp.ccp', 'w') as file2:
        file2.write(func_code.groups()[0].strip() or '')

    print func_code.groups()[0].strip()
else:
    print '%s not found!' % x
```

**Update:** Current code only returns content of function.

Comment: I tried your code, but always return 'setRunnable not found!', and I have 'setRunnable' in a line from the file.

Comment: write specific part of cpp file that you needs for me.

Comment: My cpp file looks like this:  void setRunnableStage01()
{
        g_runBli.setLimit(60);
        g_runCoffe.setLimit(100);}  A lot of function like this, and I need to copy g_runBli.setLimit(60);
        g_runCoffe.setLimit(100) in this example in another cpp file, that looks similar, so I have to found the void setRunnableStage02()  function  in the other cpp file and copy right here. I hope you understand something.

Comment: On the your code you set the `x` equal to `setRunnable` and i search for function that starts with this name, my code changed, by change `x` value you can find new functions that name starts by x value.

Comment: I tried with your updated code and again I receive only "setRunnable not found!", and I have setRunnable in my input. For you is working? You tried?

Comment: I update again my code, in http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6InZvaWRcXHMrc2V0UnVubmFibGVcXHcqXFwoXFwpW157XSouKihbXn1dKykiLCJmbGFncyI6OCwibWF0Y2hfdHlwZSI6InNlYXJjaCIsInRlc3Rfc3RyaW5nIjoidm9pZCBkb01lbVN0YWdlMDIoKVxue1xuICBmX3J1bkZsb3coZ19mbG93bSk7ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gIGZfcnVuRmxvdzIoZ19mbG93bTIpOyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIFxufVxudm9pZCBzZXRSdW5uYWJsZTAyKClcbntcbiAgICAgICAgZl9ydW5CbGkoNjApO1xuICAgICAgICBmX3J1bkNvZmZlKDEwMCk7XG59In0%3D link this pattern is correct.

Comment: In your link is only "void\s+setRunnable\w*\(\)[^{]*.*([^}]+)"

Comment: Please read more about regular expression, in above link you can check pattern, try again the code in my answer.